Stream audio back to Twilio from Azure text to speech
I am trying to send an audio stream back to Twilio via a WebSocket and let Twilio play that voice to the caller. I have set up my bidirectional WebSocket connection following this guide. I can receive the call stream but even though I am sending the audio back, I cannot hear any response.
This is how i am creating the bidirectional stream:
const response = new VoiceResponse();
const connect = response.connect();
const stream = connect.stream({
  url: "wss://<my_websocket_address>",
});
response.say("Disconnecting call");
res.type("text/xml");
res.send(response.toString());

this is how i am trying to convert the text to audio using azure-cognitive-services:
const textToSpeech = async (text) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
      constants.subscriptionkey,
      constants.region
    );
    speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = "en-US";
    speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-AvaMultilingualNeural";
    speechConfig.speechSynthesisOutputFormat = sdk.SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat.Raw8Khz8BitMonoMULaw;

    let audioConfig = null;
    const synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

     synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
       text,
       (result) => {
         const { audioData } = result;

         synthesizer.close();
         const bufferStream = new PassThrough();
         bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(audioData).toString("base64"));
         console.log("TTS DONE");
         resolve(bufferStream);
       }
      },
      (error) => {
        synthesizer.close();
        reject(error);
      }
    ); 
  });
};

and this is how i am finally trying to send the audio back:
let payload = await tts.textToSpeech("Hello, how can i help you?")
var json = {
  "event": "media",
  "streamSid": "MZ058f55e473ebabd11f57552bc9952861",
  "media": {
    "payload": payload
  }
}
this.connection.send(json)

I understand that I need to send a base64 encoded mulaw audio to Twilio but i think I am aready doing that.
Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong? Also, is there any way to check the sent WebSocket messages on the Twilio dashboard?

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.
You need to stringify your JSON object that you're sending to twilio.
this.connection.send(JSON.stringify(json))

